# How do I use comparator with is_transparent type?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdset

with C++14 we are allowed to compare elements of some associative containers (like std::set) with other types than the ones stored in a container. It's supposed to work when comparator has `is_transparent` denoted as a type (see e.g. [std::set::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find)).

Suppose I have a string wrapper which performs some checks on a string (if it's format is valid format and so on - not really important, but constructing it is heavy enough that I'd like to avoid it + it can throw exceptions) and it's stored in std::set to have a container of unique values. How should I write a comparator for it? Should it look like like the one below? Can I overload and use my `sw::operator<()` to achieve the same?

```
class sw
{
public:
    explicit sw(const std::string& s) : s_(s) { /* dragons be here */ }
    const std::string& getString() const { return s_; }

    bool operator<(const sw& other) const { return s_ < other.s_; }

private:
    std::string s_;
};

struct Comparator
{
    using is_transparent = std::true_type;

    bool operator()(const sw& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const { return lhs.getString() < rhs; }
    bool operator()(const std::string& lhs, const sw& rhs) const { return lhs < rhs.getString(); }
    bool operator()(const sw& lhs, const sw& rhs) const { return lhs < rhs; }
};

int main() 
{
    std::set<sw, Comparator> swSet{ sw{"A"}, sw{"B"}, sw{"C"} };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (swSet.find(std::string("A")) != swSet.end()) << std::endl;
}
```

I believe that above code should work as expected, but when I tested it with g++4.9 and clang++3.6, both yielded errors about missing conversion from `string` to `key_type` as if string overloads of `Comparator::operator()` were never taken into account. Am I missing something?

Comment: The version of libstdc++ (gcc's standard library) that comes with g++4.9 hasn't implemented heterogeneous lookup. Your code [compiles fine with clang and libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97c0421099d7912d).

Comment: @T.C.: thanks, that makes sense and that's what I was afraid of... I tried it with clang and -stdlib=libc++ and it worked as intended. Too bad that my default environment is g++ and libstdc++.

Comment: It's implemented in https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=219888, less than two weeks ago.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that code is correct, but it would be simpler to overload `operator<` to allow comparing your type with `std::string` and then just use `std::less<>` (i.e. `std::less<void>`) which is "transparent" already.

```
inline bool operator<(const sw& lhs, const std::string& rhs) { return lhs.getString() < rhs; }
inline bool operator<(const std::string& lhs, const sw& rhs) { return lhs < rhs.getString(); }

std::set<sw, std::less<>> swSet{ sw{"A"}, sw{"B"}, sw{"C"} };
```

Also, it's possibly worth noting that it doesn't matter what you define `is_transparent` to, either of these would have the same effect as your definition of it:

```
using is_transparent = std::false_type;

using is_transparent = void;
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't know about `less<void>` and its behaviour, that's nice. Still, when doing things like that, I find a separate comparator cleaner and more expressive, but that's probably a personal preference. :)